# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrogram'

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, linux-mint, python

i am trying to execute a python script but i always get the error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrogram' .
So i did pip3 install pyrogram and pyrogram module got installed successfully , still at end i am getting same error when trying to execute python script.
I am using linux mint 19.3 if that helps.
Below i am posting the whole output --

```
xd003@xd003:~/mirror-bot$ python3 generate_string_session.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_string_session.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyrogram import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrogram'
xd003@xd003:~/mirror-bot$ pip3 install pyrogram
Collecting pyrogram
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/6d/ffe5c490dce53d179ec7d1326190ea2efa7089ed3a7b3a37689899e10a32/Pyrogram-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyaes==1.6.1 (from pyrogram)
Collecting pysocks==1.7.0 (from pyrogram)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/18/102cc70347486e75235a29a6543f002cf758042189cb063ec25334993e36/PySocks-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pyaes, pysocks, pyrogram
Successfully installed pyaes-1.6.1 pyrogram-0.16.0 pysocks-1.7.0
xd003@xd003:~/mirror-bot$ python3 generate_string_session.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_string_session.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyrogram import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrogram'
xd003@xd003:~/mirror-bot$
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix the issue with pyaes module:

```
  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyaes
  Running setup.py clean for pyaes
Failed to build pyaes
```

There are several solutions suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819221/why-is-python-setup-py-saying-invalid-command-bdist-wheel-on-travis-ci
Most likely the solution is:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc libpq-dev -y
sudo apt-get install python-dev  python-pip -y
sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv python3-wheel -y
pip3 install wheel
```

After the issue is solved you need to make sure that whole the installation is passing **without errors from scratch**:

```
pip3 uninstall pysocks, pyaes, pyrogram
pip3 install pyrogram
```

Comment: Thanks for answering , it just happened i solved that pyaes thing seconds ago by doing pip3 install whell  but the pyrogram Error still continues

Comment: I have updated the output in question

Comment: Then you need to remove the pyrogram and try to install it again:
pip3 uninstall pyrogram; pip3 install pyrogram

Comment: tried but still facing error - https://del.dog/pyrograme.txt

Comment: Ok, I still think the issue is linked to the error that you had in the beginning with pyaes somehow, maybe it is still broken. Please try one more thing:
pip3 uninstall pysocks, pyaes, pyrogram